# Cloud Formation init script cfn-init cancellation

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudformation, amazon-linux

I used to Drupal Cloud Formation sample template to create my Drupal based web site.
But now every time my EC2 instance reboot Cloud Formation helper script cfn-init reloads original Drupal installation files  and rewrite them into my web site's home folder.

How can I disable cfn-init script?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to completely disable it (although not recommended) as root:

```
yum remove cloud-init
```

Otherwise, your Drupal installation might have installed a specific config for cloud init. Look under `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg` or any configuration file under `/etc/cloud`. Disable/delete anything that Drupal might have installed or modified.